# how to find p-values from the correlation raster

Tags: r, geospatial, correlation

I would like to calculate p-value and merge it with the correlation raster map
but I have no idea how to calculate raster p-value and marge it with the correlation raster map. 
My R programming code is shown as below

```
 r.stack <- stack
(y13,y14,y15,y16,y17,y18,y19,y20,y21,y22,y23,y24,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9,y10,y11,y12)
z1 <- r.stack[[1:12]]
z2 <- r.stack[[13:24]]
z3 <- stack(z1,z2)


r <- calc(z3, fun=function(x) cor(x[1:12], x[13:24], method='pearson'))

plot(r,col=colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "blue"))(255))

# I have no idea how to get P- value from the Correlation #
```

while y1 to y12 are Drought (SEPI) raster image and
      y 13 to 24 are NDVI raster image

Thank you in advance for any help.....

Comment: Please share code instead of screenshots that are not even readable.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mtoto  .... I corrected it .... thank you for your suggestion ^^

Comment: @Cliff Burton .... I corrected it .... thank you for your suggestion ^^

Answer (score 2):

I have got the answer already and hopefully it may help other people too.
I the `corLocal` intend of `corr` . The code is shown below,

`r.stack <- stack (y13,y14,y15,y16,y17,y18,y19,y20,y21,y22,y23,y24 ,y3, y4,y5,y6, y7,y8,y9,y10,y11,y12,y1,y2)`

`z1 <- r.stack[[1:12]]
z2 <- r.stack[[13:24]]
z3 <- stack(z1,z2)`

`r <- corLocal(r.stack[[1:12]], r.stack[[13:24]], test=TRUE )
plot(r) # r and p-value map will be shown`

`# only correlation cells where the p-value < 0.05 will be ommited`

`r.mask <- mask(r[[1]], r[[2]] < 0.05, maskvalue=FALSE)`

`plot(r.mask)`